# Network X. Creating edges

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I need to go through each point in my coordinate list. Make a edge between it and each of its nearest neighbours.

But I am getting some edges (100,100) , (40,40) . For example:

my textfile has the following inside

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors


import networkx as nx



#Get coordinates
f_name = 'bunny'
#coord = np.genfromtxt(str(f_name)+'.txt',autostrip=True)
coord = np.random.randn(200, 6)

#Fit nearest neighbours to coordinates
neigh = NearestNeighbors(3) 
neigh.fit(coord[:,:3])


#Create a graph
G = nx.Graph() 

#Add all points and there neighbours to graph, make the weight equal to the distance between points
for i in range(0,len(coord)):


    d = neigh.kneighbors(coord[i,:3]) 

    k = 3
    for c in range(0,k):
        p1 = d[1][0][0]
        p2 = d[1][0][c]
        n1 = coord[d[1][0][0],3:6]
        n2 = coord[d[1][0][c],3:6]
        dot = np.dot(n1,n2)

        G.add_edge(p1,p2,weight =1-np.abs(dot))
print G.edges()
```

example: if i loop through my edges , i will get the following in some lines

(1881, 1881)
(1881, 1882)
(1882, 1882)

Comment: Can you add your data or some sample data that generates your issue?

Comment: @MrE Sure i randomly generated numbers, thanks.

Comment: I have solved the problem...It should read for c in range(1,k): Now  i  need to minimum span the tree and depth search it starting at a point.Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, all in here with examples: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.html